# Django passing **kwargs between Form and List view

Tags: django, python-3.x, request, keyword-argument

I'm fairly new to Django and am trying to complete some code in which I have a form where the user enters a date range so "start_date & end_date" once entered i want it to redirect to a list view and to pass the **kwargs. I've had a lot of trouble with this and finally came up with a way to go about it, but it probably looks like a developers nightmare.

My issues so far is when i had it as two separate views i couldn't get the **kwargs to pass over at all, it just listed all results.

Views.py

```
class BirthdayRangeFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'snippets/date_selection_form.html'
    form_class = datefilterform

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(BirthdayRangeFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs ['request'] = self.request  
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = "Date Selection"
        context['header'] = "Please select date range"
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.start_date = (form.cleaned_data['start_date'], Person.next_birthday)
        self.end_date = (form.cleaned_data['end_date'], Person.next_birthday)
        return self.redirect_to_results()

    def redirect_to_results(self):
        self.success_url = "dates:birthdays"
        return redirect(
            self.get_success_url(),
        )

    if redirect_to_results:
        class BirthdayRangeFormView(ListView):
            template_name = 'dates/birthdays.html',
            context_object_name = "people"
            people = True

            def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
                if self.people:
                    qs = qs.filter(
                        classification__in=people,
                    )
                else:
                    qs = qs.exclude(
                        classification__in=people,
                    )

                qs = qs.filter(
                    next_birthday__range=(
                        parse(
                            kwargs.get(
                                'start_date',
                                month_start(timezone.now()).date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                            )
                        ),
                        parse(
                            kwargs.get(
                                'end_date',
                                month_end(timezone.now()).date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                            )
                        ),
                    )
                )
                return qs.order_by('next_birthday')
```

I'm looking for a better way to structure this code, any further information needed just let me know.

Thanks

Model used is called "Person".

Comment: This doesn't make any sense as it is. Why would you define a class inside an if statement, especially as you don't then return it anywhere so it is just lost? Note though, the way to pass data between views if you don't want it in the URL is to use the session.

Comment: @DanielRoseman so by me doing the If statement and def get_queryset it isnt actually passing the queryset to display?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. A view needs to be associated with a URL; how can you do that if you only define it inside an if block?